# Using Dalli to connect to memcached

Tags: ruby, cache

I always seem to struggle refactoring my code. I can look at any other code and know exactly what is going on, but when it comes to cleaning up my code, I get writers block.

The following code works, but I know if can be done much nicer, and with few lines of code. I just wanted to wrap a memcache client to use one server for testing and another for dev/prod or just fetch the value if it cannot connect to the server.

Any tips on refactoring, etc. are much appreciated.

```
require 'dalli'
class Cache
    def self.fetch(key, ttl, &block)
        if memcache
            memcache.fetch(key, ttl, &block)
        else
            block.call
        end
    end

    def self.memcache
        begin
        if(ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :production or ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :development)
            @memcache ||= Dalli::Client.new('cache.amazonaws.com:11211')    
        else
            @memcache ||= Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211')  
        end
        rescue Exception => e
            false
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This DRY's the code in `self.memcache` and simply uses a ternary operator for `self.fetch`.

```
require 'dalli'
class Cache
  def self.fetch(key, ttl, &block)
    memcache ? memcache.fetch(key, ttl, &block) : block.call
  end

  def self.memcache
    @memcache ||= Dalli::Client.new((ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :production or ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :development) ?
                                    'cache.amazonaws.com:11211' :
                                    'localhost:11211')
  rescue Exception
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: The begin and end keywords you get for free inside the block that is a method definition.

Comment: I'd change some indentation and blank lines, but basically this is it. One important thing though: dont' write `rescue Exception`, always `rescue StandardError`.

Comment: Generally true, tokland, but Exception was what was given in the original question, so rather than assume they are rescuing the wrong thing, I stuck with it.  It was not clear what they intended to rescue, though that is likely overreaching.  I am sure it wasn't a comment to me, though, I am just saying.  The indentation is only there to show a new user what the important part of the above line is, which is to indicate the two options below would be resulting in that parenthesis level.  I tried to not affect behavior, only what they asked for.  @gp, you want to answer about Exception choice?

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like this, if I really want to have `fetch` as a class method. If that is not mandatory, I would make `fetch` the only public instance method, and the rest private instance methods.

```
 require 'dalli'

 class Cache
   def self.fetch(key, ttl, &block)
     memcache ? memcache.fetch(key, ttl, &block) : block.call
   end

   def self.memcache
     @memcache ||= new_client
   end

   def self.new_client
     begin
       Dalli::Client.new(memcache_host)
     rescue StandardError
       false
     end
   end

   def self.memcache_host
     (production? || development?) ? 'cache.amazonaws.com:11211' : 'localhost:11211'    
   end

   def self.production?
     environment == :production
   end

   def self.development?
     environment == :development
   end

   def self.environment
     ENV['RACK_ENV']
   end
 end
```

Comment: I like it.  Still the begin and end are implicit by virtue of being in a block, this block being the method definition.

Comment: I just don't like the un-indented `rescue`. Same as the indented or un-indented `private` statement, some like it one way, others like the other :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like the following:

```
require 'dalli'
class Cache
    def self.fetch(key, ttl, &block)
        memcache and
            memcache.fetch(key, ttl, &block) or
            block.call
    end

    def self.host
        @host ||= (ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :production || ENV['RACK_ENV'] == :development) ?
            'cache.amazonaws.com:11211' :
            'localhost:11211'
    end

    def self.memcache   
        @memcache ||= Dalli::Client.new(host)
    rescue StandardError
        nil
    end
end
```

I prefer returning `nil` instead of `false` on methods that would otherwise return an object on success.  If it returns `false` on failure, then it should return `true` on success, but that would then change the method's name to `memcache`.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer. `Cache::fetch` and `Cache::host` are confusing. The the ternary disguised as and `and`/`or` is ambiguous (`(a and b) or c` or `a and (b or c)`). The ternary in `Cache::host`, like the one in `Cache::fetch` is so long, it's split it into multiple lines. They would both be clearer as regular `if` statements. `Cache::memcache` silently swallows *every* exception inheriting from `StandardError`, making debugging hard. Introducing `Cache::host` is a good decision, it makes `Cache::memcache` clear and concise.

Comment: If you know Ruby, you should know that the `and` and `or` operators behave similarly to bash's `&&` and `||`.  So order of operation should be a non-issue. It's like saying `(5 * 3) + 2`. Redundant.  Long ternary operations are non-issue.  If we look at David's answer, where he split the env check into their own functions, it can be a good idea if the rest of the system also could take advantage of the env check. But from the question alone, we don't know if that's even needed.

Comment: The precedence rules for `and`/`or` are unintuitive (and, more importantly, different from the more popular `&&`/`||`!). I have to look them up all the time. I had to look quite a bit longer at the `and`/`or` construction in `Cache::fetch` to recognize it as a simple if statement. An if statement would have made it crystal clear that it is an if statement. Fun example: `a = nil or "foo"` (`a` is now `nil`, but the return value is `"foo"`).